# Arabic characters from Base64 to HTML

Tags: html, mysql, character-encoding, base64

I am getting data from android mobile, i store it in mysql db and then i have to display that on a webpage. It works for English characters but for other foreign language characters it doesn't (like Arabic, Persian, Kannada, etc). So i decided to send in base64 format from mobile, i store it in base64 format in mysql db and while displaying on webpage i decode it back from base64 to normal characters but that not working. It shows in this format:

```
ÙØ§ ÙÙ Ø§ÙØ´ÙØ±Ø© Ø§ÙÙÙØ­Ø¯Ø© "ÙÙÙÙÙÙØ¯" Ø
```

Code used in perl:

```
my $cgi = new CGI '-utf8';
use MIME::Base64;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
use Encode 'decode_utf8';

print $cgi->header(
-type => 'text/html',
-charset => 'utf8',
);


print qq~<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>~;

print decode_base64("2YXYpyDZh9mKINin2YTYtNmB2LHYqSDYp9mE2YXZiNit2K/YqSAi2YrZiNmG2ZDZg9mI2K8iINif");

print qq~</body></html>~;
```

The decode_base64 converts back to Arabic character but it doesnt work in browser.

Is there anything i am missing or its not possible to store arabic characters in base64 in db and convert on the fly to html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after i removed `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";` here is the simplified version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
use MIME::Base64;

print $cgi->header(
-charset => 'utf8',
);

print qq~<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html> <meta name="description" content="Displaying foreign languages with incompatible character sets using Unicode."/>
</head>
<body>~;
print decode_base64("2YXYpyDZh9mKINin2YTYtNmB2LHYqSDYp9mE2YXZiNit2K/YqSAi2YrZiNmG2ZDZg9mI2K8iINif");

print qq~</body></html>~;
```